# How to replace special character using regex in Mule Dataweave transformation?

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

Suppose I have an XML file of details of employee such as id, name and address and now I want to convert it into JSON file and before the conversation I want to replace specified special character (- , /) with blank space in address field of json document

below are my **Dataweave transformation code**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    Id: payload01 .d as :string,
    Name: payload01.Name as :string, 
    Address: payload01.Address replace /(?)/ with " "
})
```

So what should I write within replace /()/ function to replace specials character **,** **-** and **/** with **blank space**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
Address: payload01.Address replace /([\-\,\/])/ with " "
```